# On Change recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, datepicker, onchange

Funny problem, please help...

I have a page with a list of products. Every product has it's own date input field.
When you change the date for one product, all other products needs to get that same date (if I set the date for first product to 1.1.2018. all other products date fields gets filled with 1.1.2018.).

What I'm doing is:

```
$('input[name="productDate"]').on('change', function () {
    $('input[name="productDate"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

This is simplified version. I'm using jquery datepicker with alternative field which triggers change event when manually setting the date.
So my stupid recursive function runs forever until I get

> Maximum call stack size exceeded error.

How can I stop this function to run after every date on the list is changed? Or is there something smarter to do?

And don't ask why I just don't put one input date for all products... not on me to decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop thru each element and do change the value only if it's different.

```js
$('input[name="productDate"]').on('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val()
    
    $('input[name="productDate"]').each(function () {
      if ($(this).val() != value) {
        $(this).val(value).change() // just a trigger test
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
```

Or simple exclude current element

```
$('input[name="productDate"]').not(this).val($(this).val())
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Has a method `stopPropagation()` that stops actions from triggering further events.  It should be useful in your situation.

```js
$('input[name="productDate"]').on('change', function (e) {
  $('input[name="productDate"]').val($(this).val());
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="productDate">
<input type="text" name="productDate">
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

An easy solution is to add a flag to stop propagating the change if a previous one is already in progress; see the snippet below.

**Solution 2:**

Check if the value of the input is already the same.

**Solution 3:**

The easiest solution is to simply call for event.stopPrpogation. Actually, this the solution that I would go for, but I am not sure whether in your application you need the event to be propagated for other places.

```js
$('input[name="productDate"]').on('change', function() {
  if (this.__editing) {
    return;
  }
  this.__editing = true;
  $('input[name="productDate"]').val($(this).val());
  delete this.__editing;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="productDate" value="Product1">
<input name="productDate" value="Product2">
<input name="productDate" value="Product3">
<input name="productDate" value="Product4">
```